# Jenkins: PasswordParameterValue.value expects String but received Secret

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jenkins job, a parent-job which takes password and parent job then passes this information to a separate jenkins child-job, which is expecting a password parameters. I am getting an error as mentioned below.

```
ERROR:
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.model.PasswordParameterValue.value expects class java.lang.String but received class hudson.util.Secret
```

--

```
parent-job:
pipeline {
    agent any   
    stages {
        stage('Parameters'){
            steps {
                script {
                properties([
                        parameters([
                            password(defaultValue: '', name: 'uma_auth_client_secret'),
                            password(defaultValue: '', name: 'pki_client_cacert_password'),
                            password(defaultValue: '', name: 'db_url')
                        ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy'){
            steps {
                script {
                        def jobBuild = build job: child-job, propagate: false, parameters: [
                            password(name: 'uma_auth_client_secret', value :params.uma_auth_client_secret),
                            password(name: 'pki_client_cacert_password', value: params.pki_client_cacert_password),
                            password(name:'db_url', value: params.db_url)
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
child-job:
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    parameters {
    password(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'pki_client_cacert_password')
    password(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'db_url')
    }

        stage('DeployToDev') {
                steps {
                    script{
                        withEnv(["ENV_PKI_CLIENT_CACERT_PASSWORD=${params.pki_client_cacert_password}", "ENV_DB_URL=${params.db_url}"]) {
                            ....
                            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my ask is to

1. help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem as follows, I created jenkins credentials and I was able to push those values to downstream `'child-job'` job

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
    stages {
        stage('Parameters'){
            steps {
                script {
                properties([
                        parameters([
                            password(defaultValue: '', name: 'uma_auth_client_secret'),
                            password(defaultValue: '', name: 'pki_client_cacert_password'),
                            password(defaultValue: '', name: 'db_url')
                        ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy'){
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials(
                        [
                            string(credentialsId: 'uma_auth_client_secret_o2', variable: 'uma_auth_client_secret'),
                            string(credentialsId: 'db_url_o2', variable: 'db_url'),
                            string(credentialsId: 'pki_client_cacert_password_o2', variable: 'pki_client_cacert_password')
                        ]
                        ){
                            def jobBuild = build job: "child-job", propagate: false, parameters: [
                            password(name: 'uma_auth_client_secret', value : "${uma_auth_client_secret}"),
                            password(name:'db_url', value: "${db_url}"),
                            password(name: 'pki_client_cacert_password', value: "${pki_client_cacert_password}")
                        ]
                        
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having input parameters if you're just using values from the credential manager?